# Unit testing conformance to Decodable using a SingleValueDecodingContainer

Tags: swift, unit-testing, codable, decodable

So, I have a type which looks like this:

```
struct Identifier {
    let string: String
}

extension Identifier: Decodable {
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        string = try container.decode(String.self)
    }
}
```

The point with this type is if I have JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "identifier": "abc123",
    // more properties ...
}
```

... it will automatically be serialized to the correct type without much effort. However, I'm having trouble unit testing this conformance to `Decodable` without creating a wrapping type.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
func testDecodableInit() {
    let identifier = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Identifier.self, from: "1".data(using: .utf8)!)
    XCTAssertEqual(identifier.string, "1")
}
```

But obviously this doesn't work because `"1"` is not valid JSON.

Is it possible to write a unit test for this conformance to `Decodable` without creating a wrapping type and changing the data to valid JSON?

Comment: What is the goal of this test? To verify that an error is thrown for invalid/incorrect JSON?

Comment: Yes, that a string represented in JSON can be converted to `Identifier`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave up trying to accomplish this without creating a wrapping type on the assumption that it's very hard to decode a string that isn't valid JSON to begin with (`'1'` in my example).

So, I guess, the answer is: just create a wrapping type. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 6):

If someones wondering how to create a test with a wrapping type. It looks like this;

```
struct Identifier {
    let string: String
}

extension Identifier: Decodable {
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        string = try container.decode(String.self)
    }
}
```

And our test will look like this;

```
class IdentifierTests: XCTestCase {

    func testStringValueDecodedSuccessfully() throws {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let data = Data("{\"value\": \"identifier-string\"}".utf8)
        let container = try decoder.decode(Wrapper1.self, from: data)
        XCTAssertEqual(container.identifierValue.string, "identifier-string")
    }
}

private struct Wrapper: Decodable {

    let identifierValue: Identifier

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case value
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        identifierValue = try container.decode(Identifier.self, forKey: .value)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative. It's more code because you have to implement all the methods of the `Decoder` and `SingleValueDecodingContainer` protocols but the test looks a lot cleaner:

In my case, I had to parse the value, not just store it. Hence the reason for the test.

Your test would look like:

```
func testDecode() throws {
    let value = try Identifier(from: StringDecoder(text: "1"))
    XCTAssertEqual(value.string, "1")
}
```

My test looks like:

```
func testDecode() throws {
    let yearMonth = try YearMonth(from: StringDecoder(text: "2022-02-01T00:00:00"))
    XCTAssertEqual(yearMonth, YearMonth(year: 2022, month: 2))
}
```

The support code is below. Is it worth it? You be the judge.

```
struct StringDecoder: Decoder {
    let text: String
    var codingPath: [CodingKey] { XCTFail(); return [] }
    var userInfo: [CodingUserInfoKey : Any] { XCTFail(); return [:] }

    init(text: String) {
        self.text = text
    }

    func container<Key>(keyedBy type: Key.Type) throws -> KeyedDecodingContainer<Key> where Key : CodingKey {
        throw BadDecode()
    }

    func unkeyedContainer() throws -> UnkeyedDecodingContainer {
        throw BadDecode()
    }

    func singleValueContainer() throws -> SingleValueDecodingContainer {
        ValueDecoder(text: text)
    }
}

struct ValueDecoder: SingleValueDecodingContainer {
    let text: String
    var codingPath: [CodingKey] { XCTFail(); return [] }

    func decodeNil() -> Bool {
        XCTFail()
        return false
    }

    func decode(_ type: Bool.Type) throws -> Bool {
        throw BadDecode()
    }

    func decode(_ type: String.Type) throws -> String {
        return text
    }

    func decode(_ type: Double.Type) throws -> Double {
        throw BadDecode()
    }

    func decode(_ type: Float.Type) throws -> Float {
        throw BadDecode()
    }

    func decode(_ type: Int.Type) throws -> Int {
        throw BadDecode()
    }

    func decode(_ type: Int8.Type) throws -> Int8 {
        throw BadDecode()
    }

    func decode(_ type: Int16.Type) throws -> Int16 {
        throw BadDecode()
    }

    func decode(_ type: Int32.Type) throws -> Int32 {
        throw BadDecode()
    }

    func decode(_ type: Int64.Type) throws -> Int64 {
        throw BadDecode()
    }

    func decode(_ type: UInt.Type) throws -> UInt {
        throw BadDecode()
    }

    func decode(_ type: UInt8.Type) throws -> UInt8 {
        throw BadDecode()
    }

    func decode(_ type: UInt16.Type) throws -> UInt16 {
        throw BadDecode()
    }

    func decode(_ type: UInt32.Type) throws -> UInt32 {
        throw BadDecode()
    }

    func decode(_ type: UInt64.Type) throws -> UInt64 {
        throw BadDecode()
    }

    func decode<T>(_ type: T.Type) throws -> T where T : Decodable {
        throw BadDecode()
    }
}

struct BadDecode: Error { }
```